# Does scipy.stats.pearsonr() have assumption of continuous value?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, scipy

**Problem**

I have to calculate correlation between two variables, let's say, variable A and B. Variable A contains discrete values - "How many times a student has done a task?". Variable B contains continuous values - students CGPA. Since [article 1](https://journals.lww.com/anesthesia-analgesia/Fulltext/2018/05000/Correlation_Coefficients__Appropriate_Use_and.50.aspx), [article 2](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/pearson-correlation-assumptions/), [article 3](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/pearsons-product-moment-correlation-using-spss-statistics.php) say to meet the assumption of continuous variable at the time of pearson correlation calculation, I think both variables have to be continuous along with meeting some other major assumptions (e.g Normally distributed, No. Outlier). However, in the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html), they did not mention about the continuous assumption of `scipy.stats.pearsonr()` method.

**What confuses me?**

Since some articles have mentioned to meet the assumption of continuous variable, I also agree to meet that. However, since citing some articles, [they](https://journals.lww.com/anesthesia-analgesia/Fulltext/2018/05000/Correlation_Coefficients__Appropriate_Use_and.50.aspx) mention,

> Assumptions of a Pearson correlation have been intensely debated.It is therefore not surprising, but nonetheless confusing, that *different statistical resources present different assumptions*.

This confuses me whether `scipy.stats.pearsonr()` method internally do continuous correction as they do regarding [Mann Whitney Test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html) by default.

**My Question**

Should I meet the assumption of continuous variable also to use `scipy.stats.pearsonr()` method when the major assumptions have meet (Normally distributed, No. Outlier)?

Comment: *Calculating* the correlation coefficient requires no assumptions whatsoever.  Such assumptions are involved in *interpreting* it.  Please explain, then, how you intend to use the results of the calculation.

Comment: Can you please cite a paper or reliable article where they have mentioned "no assumptions is required to calculate these correlation values"? I apology since I know very less.

Comment: I think no citation is needed beyond quoting the formula: whatever formula you choose to use (they are all algebraically equivalent) will demonstrate the correlation coefficient can be computed whenever both variables are non-constant.